# Open Unity App from Android App Widget and deep link

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I'm still working my way around Android Studios and java, so I don't have a complete understanding yet of how it all works (trying to learn while doing).

I have an app that is built out from Unity 3D and imported into Android Studios. I then added an app widget to it. The app widget functions fine and I have been able to update it and have it update daily without issues so far.

Next thing I need is the ability to tap on it and have it go to a certain place in the app. I know this can be done with deep linking type stuff and I did notice that the UnityPlayerActivity has the method

```
@Override protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    // To support deep linking, we need to make sure that the client can get access to
    // the last sent intent. The clients access this through a JNI api that allows them
    // to get the intent set on launch. To update that after launch we have to manually
    // replace the intent with the one caught here.
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

I'm not sure if or how I might use this. (or even if this is what I need to use). I also had considered setting a PlayerPref (I think they are SharedPrefs I can access from what I had been reading), or even just setting a variable in one of the Java files to read in when the app opens. But I think a deep link would be best.

I know I would also want to detect if the app is already open and I saw mention of a UnitySendMessage I believe it was to make a call to a gameobject.

The issue I'm running into is I'm having trouble figuring out how to hook everything I need to a tap on the widget. I was able to get the app to open using the following code

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
        R.layout.verse_of_the_day);

Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.company.app",
        UnityPlayerActivity.class.getName()));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 0, intent, 0);

views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent);
```

This worked and I can tap the widget and the app does open, but now I need it to open to a certain part when the widget is tapped on, or just open normally if the icon is tapped on.

I appreciate any insight into what I need to change on this.